# deviceready only fire after 30 seconds in iOS 10

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, device

I deviceready doesn't fire or fires very late in my ionic app when I run it on my iOS device with

```
ionic run ios --device -lcs
```

I removed all the plugins with `ionic plugin rm ...`, deleted the content of the `plugins/` directory and reinstalled them.
I also removed and reinstalled the ios platform with `ionic platform rm/add ios`.

I am stuck with this.

The iPhone (6+) is on iOS 10.

I am using ionic 1, and the last ionic CLI.

**EDIT:** I removed all plugins one by one, and its seems that the problem is due to cordova-plugin-network-information and cordova-plugin-device.

```
Process 663 detached
(lldb) 
(node:26790) DeprecationWarning: Using Buffer without `new` will soon stop working. Use `new Buffer()`, or preferably `Buffer.from()`, `Buffer.allocUnsafe()` or `Buffer.alloc()` instead.

14    030280   warn     Native: deviceready did not fire within 2000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them.
15    030605   info     [object Object]
16    033286   log      deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
17    033290   log      Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady
18    033293   log      Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady
19    363977   log      DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER, 32259, ms
```

My run.js, AppCtrl.js and the controller of my main view are encapsultaed in $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {..});`

My content security policy is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; connect-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' blob: ws: *;">
```

Comment: Please enclose a [MCVE] to demonstrate this.

Comment: I added the error code

Comment: Please show the start up code that you have that is causing the issue.

Comment: but my app has more than 10 plugins, and it's huge amount of code !

Comment: We can't help you, we're not mind readers, we're not remote debuggers...use pastebin.com or similar site. or even a github's gist.

Comment: ok ! done ;) I posted my run.js

Comment: You are doing too much, all the initialisation of code  try moving the `$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {` to the top... to ensure that the deviceready does fire. You will have to re-arrange the code in a way that it does fire consistently.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, I mean the issue is that deviceready didn't fire, so how come moving the .ready will change anything ?  And what do you mean by "you are doing too much"?

Comment: Can someone help me here ?

Comment: ok if I remove the plugin "cordova-plugin-network-information", the deviceready fires at 1 second

Comment: Hi @Louis, i too had the same problem on ios devices, on 9.3 everything worked fine but on ios 10 i got this problem. All you needed to do was to remove the network-information plugin?

Comment: Hi @Sombriks, thanks for your answer ! I am not alone here yoohoo !  I had to remove cordova-plugin-network-information and cordova-plugin-device.... now I am readding all other plugins right now to see if everyting is fine....but those two plugins are mandatory. What did you do to make it work ?

Comment: Right now i'm building a clean project and re-adding each plugin one by one. your story helps me and many others

Comment: ok I see, I am doing the same, ok I got all my plugin installed, except device and network-information....and deviceready fires in less than one second on ios10. Maybe there's a bug with ionic

Comment: i got an alternative solution, that might help to put the offensive plugins back. first i did a few remote debugs: http://geeklearning.io/apache-cordova-and-remote-debugging-on-ios/ later i figured out i was lacking a security policy for gap:// schema: https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/cordova-security-whitlists/#the-csp-in-cordova i also updated cordova and ios platform. you might need to force it to the latest version with "cordova platform add ios@4.3.1"

Comment: Thanks @Sombriks the content security policy seems to be the issue.Thanks for your response @baviskarmitesh. But I had to add `gap` to the content security policy and now it seems to work.

I added `data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'`after `default-src *` like this:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
  default-src * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval';
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;
  connect-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' blob: ws: *;
">`

Comment: anyone knows what was the issue here ? because I don't get it really

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I added Thanks for your response @baviskarmitesh. But I had to add `gap` to the content security policy and now it seems to work.

I added `data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'`after `default-src *` into my **content security policy** in my index.html file, like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
  default-src * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval';
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;
  connect-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' blob: ws: *;
">
```

And now deviceready fires quickly with all my plugins.

Comment: Glad it worked. As i mentioned it was also something to do with content security policy too.

Comment: It helped but I also had to remove cordova-plugin-device so that DeviceReady event is fired more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a common issue with Ionic framework and there could be multiple reasons for it. One reason could be some issue with the plugin you use or could also be due to some issue in the platform folder. There seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/259) on this in Ionic CLI project.

Following could be the possible fixes for this issue:

1. Removing the faulty plugins and re-adding the same
2. Removing the platform folder and re-adding the same.
3. Probably avoid using live reload option
4. If the problem is iOS specific, then you can try relaxing the content security policy

You can also have a look at this [link](http://christianfei.com/posts/Solution-to-PhoneGap-issue-device-ready-has-not-fired-after-5-seconds/)

Hope this should help.

Comment: The open issue is about crosswalk, I am not using it. 
Your points 1 and 2 are not relevant if you read my question. (I removed/added platforms and plugins). Same for your last link.
I compiled a release version (no livereload) and the issue is still here. And anyway I need livereload to develop.
Can you please explain what you mean by "relaxing the content security policy" ? (I am adding mine in the question).

Comment: @Louis Thanks for the comments. I rechecked the issue link and its logged in ionic CLI project. Few have faced the same issue using crosswalk too but the issue is not restricted only to crosswalk I feel. Regarding content security, check out growthclick's comments in the open issue link. Also have an eye on access origin specified in config.xml