# How to add Content Security Policy in index.html

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, device

I am developing application in Ionic and when I run this application in iOS device it stucks on splashscreen for sometime and then it load.I check console and there it shows that device ready is fired after 95245 ms . That means device is taking too much time to being ready.

I search for the issue and find similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40937259) and for that accepted solution is like below:

---

### As Louis Suggest

> I added Thanks for your response @baviskarmitesh. But I had to add gap
>   to the content security policy and now it seems to work.
>
> I added data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'after
>   default-src * into my content security policy in my index.html file,
>   like this:
>
> meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="   default-src *
>   data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval';   style-src 'self'
>   'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com;   script-src 'self'
>   'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;   connect-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
>   'unsafe-eval' blob: ws: *; "> And now deviceready fires quickly with
>   all my plugins.

Now I am trying to pass this `meta` tag for `Content-Security-Policy` in my `index.html` but whenever I build my iOS app using this command.

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

This `Content-Security-Policy` meta tag is remove automatically from my `index.html`. So how can I add this `Content-Security-Policy` in my `index.html`? Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are doing the changes on the `index.html` file that is inside the `src` folder.

When you run `ionic cordova build ios`, it generates the `www` folder with the src content and Cordova uses the `www` folder content to build the app.